# Using PostgreSQL-PostGIS for coordinates

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to create a database for storing coordinates

Lets say X has: Latitude 20°20’20.00’’ , Longitude 20°20’20.00’’E , with 1 mile range.

Y has: Latitude 20°21’21.00 , Longitude 20°21’21.00’’

I want to know whether Y location lies within X range.

I've been trying for days to find a way to manage that; I came across quad tree,  k-d tree, but I could not find a way to represent it in a database.

I finally stumbled on PostGIS but I don't know how to create and manage simple latitude longitude interaction whit it.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you want to do is learn more about [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/documentation/).

After you installed the `postgis` extension, you can use the `geography` type for your purposes:

```
CREATE TABLE locations (
  id      serial PRIMARY KEY,
  loc     geography(POINT, 4326), -- See PostGIS docs for type modifiers
  rng     double precision, -- in miles, PostGIS uses km
  ...
);

CREATE INDEX locations_geo ON locations USING GIST (loc);
```

Your lat,long pairs go into the `loc` column as a `geography` type; PostGIS will do the spatial analysis with that data. You can now find all points within range of the X point (say, with `id=12`) as follows:

```
SELECT src.id AS src, src.rng, near.*
FROM locations near
JOIN locations src ON ST_DWithin(src.location, near.location, src.rng * 0.6215) -- miles to km
WHERE src.id = 12;
```